# Crash with CALayer, memory problem

Tags: iphone, memory, crash, calayer

My thanks to hotpaw2 for the solution to my incremental drawing problem.  Alas, I discovered an issue with the solution as I implemented it.  It reveals itself as a memory-induced crash when I press the botton at the bottom of the iphone to suspend the app and then restart it.  (I can run the app indefinitely as long as I don't do this).  The crash occurs at the indicated line below, which occurs in FooBar, a subclass of UIView:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// @@CRASH here: Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS 
[backingLayer renderInContext:ctx];     // Render the backing layer into current context
[self randomRectangle: ctx];

}
```

In the interface of FooBar I have declared backing layer as instance variable:

```
@private

NSTimer* timer;
CALayer *backingLayer;
```

In the implementation of FooBar, backingLayer occurs just once more, in `initWithFrame`, in the following paragraph:

```
    backingLayer = self.layer; 
    // [backingLayer retain];
    // Set its color space and background color
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat components[4] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    CGColorRef bgColor = CGColorCreate(colorSpace, components);
    backingLayer.backgroundColor = bgColor;
    CGColorRelease(bgColor);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
```

I should also say that there is an `NSTimer timer` that is defined in `initWithFrame` fires off the `tick` method below 12 times a second:

```
- (void)tick
{    
// Tell the view that it needs to re-draw itself

    if (running) {  // Go!
       //  NSLog(@"frameRate: %2.1f, frameCount: %d", frameRate, frameCount);
        [self setNeedsDisplay];
        frameCount++;
    } 
}
```

I've run Instruments on this app. No memory leaks are detected.  But when I run Allocations and (a) suspend app with physical button, (b) touch the app icon to make it run again, then I see huge cluster of allocations (~2 GB) --- and CRASH.

-- Jim

Comment: I've fixed this one.  There is a boolean variable `running` in a UIView class which as to be set to FALSE when the app becomes dormant, then set TRUE when it becomes active.  The variable `running` in the `tick` method determines whether or not `setNeedsDisplay` is called.  (The timer which calls `tick` also needs to be invalidated).

Sorry, dunno how to mark this as answered.

Answer (score 0):

See last comment, which I should have put here.  Fixed this by setting `BOOL running` to FALSE when the app enters its inactive state, resetting it to TRUE when it becomes active once again.